# Error http://hl.altervista.org/split.php in REST services

Tags: php, rest, cors, symfony

I'm trying to consume a REST service and I'm experiencing this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 10:49:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://hl.altervista.org/split.php?http://thinkmeapp.altervista.org/rest/message.json
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 269
Age: 199
Via: 1.1 itpmg030
```

I don't understand why the response is HTTP 302 ???
And what is hl.altervista.org/split.php ???

I created REST services with symfony 3.2:

```
/**
 * Get a new JWT token by username and password POST parameters.
 * 
 * @Post("/rest/token", name="fetch_jwt_token", defaults={"_format": "json"})
 */
public function fetchToken(Request $request) { ... }

/**
 * Get the owned, confirmed and unconfirmed messages of the current user.
 * 
 * @Get("/rest/message.{_format}")
 */
public function getAllUserMessages($_format) { ... }
```

and I enabled the CORS, configuring the bundle NelmioCorsBundle as the following:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: []
    allow_headers: []
    allow_methods: []
    expose_headers: []
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
paths:
    '^/rest':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['Accept', 'X-AUTH', 'Content-Type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
```

When I ask for a JWT token, the response is HTTP OK, so I get the JWT token.

When I try to consume the second service, it require a preflight request, and the server response is HTTP OK 200 that you can see here:
[WebInspector - HTTP OPTION request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4spN0.jpg)

And finally, the response of the second service go wrong (HTTP 302 redirect), and you can see it here:
[WebInspector - HTTP GET request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu8Fx.jpg)

Can you help me to fully understand what is wrong? Is the OPTION response valid? And the GET request?

-- UPDATE 2017/01/21 --
It seems that altervista use an anti-leech (see here: [what is split.php](http://forum.it.altervista.org/i-servizi-di-altervista/202004-split-php-cos.html), and so the REST response is seen as a file to download. But it is not my case. I only want a JSON. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Daniel

Comment: 302 is a redirect. The api most likely has changed the enpoint route and they are trying to redirect you to it. Normally you can setup curl or whatever you are using to make the requests to enable follow redirects.

Comment: I know HTTP 302 is a redirect, but I don't understand why. The endpoint  is specified by this annotation: @Get("/rest/message.{_format}") so it is right. And the response is hl.altervista.org/split and NOT thinkmeapp.altervista.org.